# How to get value of tensor2d in tensorflow.js model which corresponds to a numpy array

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

So I have h5 Keras Tensorflow Deep Learning model which accepts a NumPy array as an input and gives the desired numerical result in a form of a NumPy array (Python)

[image: input of a numpy array in model.predict function]

Now I want to do the same in tensorflow.js so I converted the model and imported it and used the model.predict function (JavaScript)

```
    const x = tf.tensor2d([company_name])
    const output = model.predict(x)
    console.log(output)
```

And I get this as the output

```
Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 1, 1 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 1,
  strides: [ 1 ],
  dataId: { id: 35 },
  id: 52,
  rankType: '2',
  scopeId: 0
}
```

I would like to get the actual value of the tensor2d like 38.340986 that I got in the NumPy array. I tried using

```
model.predict(x.get(0,0));
```

But it returns a type error

Help is appreciated.

Comment: How can I create a numpy array in Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download the tensors when using `Tensorflow.js`

```
const output = model.predict(x).dataSync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensors are the core datastructure of TensorFlow.js They are a generalization of vectors and matrices to potentially higher dimensions.

```
model.predict(np.array([value1], [value2])))
```

Comment: Will this work in tensorflow.js? since the NumPy array doesn't exist in javascript hence I used tensor2d as an input. But the output given in tensorflow.js is tensors properties but I want the value just like I got one in python TensorFlow.

Comment: You can try to convert and save the numpy array in other format such as json, then load and parse it as javascript array.

Numeric and array operation with numpy is not supported in tfjs. Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/layers_for_keras_users#no_numpy_for_tensorflowjs